# case..of with function

Tags: delphi, function, case

this is my program...  i need help how i can use function CalkaNadmiar for 2: in (case rgMetoda.ItemIndex of) and function CalkaNiedomiar for 3:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  fx= function(x:extended):extended;
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Naglowek: TLabel;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    Label5: TLabel;
    Label6: TLabel;
    Label7: TLabel;
    edPrzedzialy: TEdit;
    edOd: TEdit;
    edDo: TEdit;
    pnWynik: TPanel;
    Oblicz: TButton;
    rgMetoda: TRadioGroup;
    rb1: TRadioButton;
    rb2: TRadioButton;
    rb3: TRadioButton;

    function f1(X: Extended): Extended;
    function f2(X: Extended): Extended;
    function f3(X: Extended): Extended;
    procedure ObliczClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure edPrzedzialyExit(Sender: TObject);
    procedure edOdExit(Sender: TObject);
    procedure edDoExit(Sender: TObject);




  private
         function CalkaNadmiar (odx,dox:extended; n:integer; f:fx):extended;
     function CalkaNiedomiar (odx,dox:extended; n:integer; f:fx):extended;
     function Calka (odx,dox:extended; n:integer; f:fx):extended;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function TForm1.f1(x: Extended): Extended;
begin
 Result:=sqr(x)+ 2;
end;

function TForm1.f2(X: Extended): Extended;
begin
 Result:=3*x - 8;
end;

function TForm1.f3(X: Extended): Extended;
begin
 Result:=sin(x) + Pi;
end;


 procedure TForm1.ObliczClick(Sender: TObject);
var Wynik, h, xi: real;
    i,n: word;
//h - krok całkowania
// Wynik - chwilowy lub końcowy wynik danej funkcji
//xi - x dla kolejnego kroku całkowania
//n - liczba przedziałów
//i - obsluga pętli
begin
 n:=StrToInt(edPrzedzialy.Text);
 h:=(StrToFloat(edDo.Text)-StrToFloat(edOd.Text))/n;
 Wynik:=0;
 case rgMetoda.ItemIndex of
  0: begin //obsługa metody prostok±tów z nadmiarem
   if rb1.Checked then
    begin
     for i:=0 to n-1 do
      begin
       xi:=StrToFloat(edOd.Text)+i*h;
       Wynik:= Wynik + f1(xi)*h;
      end;
     pnWynik.Caption:= FloatToStr(Wynik);
    end;
   if rb2.Checked then
    begin
     for i:=0 to n-1 do
      begin
       xi:=StrToFloat(edOd.Text)+i*h;
       Wynik:= Wynik + f2(xi)*h;
       end;
        pnWynik.Caption:= FloatToStr(Wynik);
      end;
    if rb3.Checked then
      begin
       for i:=0 to n-1 do
        begin
         xi:=StrToFloat(edOd.Text)+i*h;
         Wynik:= Wynik + f3(xi)*h;
      end;
     pnWynik.Caption:=FloatToStr(Wynik);
   end;
   end;


  1: begin //obsługa metody prostok±tów z niedomiarem
   if rb1.Checked then
    begin
     for i:=1 to n do
      begin
       xi:= StrToFloat(edOd.Text) + i*h;
       Wynik:= Wynik + f1(xi)*h;
      end;
     pnWynik.Caption := FloatToStr(Wynik);
    end;
   if rb2.Checked then
    begin
     for i:=1 to n do
      begin
       xi:=StrToFloat(edOd.Text) + i*h;
       Wynik:= Wynik + f2(xi)*h;
      end;
     pnWynik.Caption:=FloatToStr(Wynik);
    end;
         if rb3.Checked then
      begin
       for i:=0 to n-1 do
        begin
         xi:=StrToFloat(edOd.Text)+i*h;
         Wynik:= Wynik + f3(xi)*h;
      end;
     pnWynik.Caption:=FloatToStr(Wynik);
  end;
end;
end;
end;


procedure TForm1.edPrzedzialyExit(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if (StrToFloat(edPrzedzialy.Text)<10000) or
    (StrToFloat(edPrzedzialy.Text)>100000000)
 then
  begin
   showmessage('Podaj liczbę z przedziału [10000 - 100000000].');
   edPrzedzialy.SetFocus;
  end;
 if Frac(StrToFloat(edPrzedzialy.Text))<>0 then
{sprawdzamy czy została wprowadzona liczba całkowita}
  begin
   showmessage('Podaj liczbę całkowitą.');
   edPrzedzialy.SetFocus;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.edOdExit(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if StrToFloat(edOd.Text)>=StrToFloat(edDo.Text) then
  begin
   showmessage('Podaj liczbę mniejsz± niż górna granica całkowania.');
   edOd.SetFocus;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.edDoExit(Sender: TObject);
begin
if StrToFloat(edDo.Text)<=StrToFloat(edOd.Text) then
  begin
   showmessage('Podaj liczbę większą niż dolna granica całkowania.');
   edDo.SetFocus;
  end;
  end;

  function TForm1.CalkaNadmiar (odx,dox:extended; n:integer; f:fx):extended; //trapez z nadmiarem
var i:integer;  xi,h,Wynik:extended;
begin
    Wynik:=0;
    h:=(Dox-Odx)/n;
for i:= 0 to n-1 do
    begin
        Wynik:=f(xi)*h+Wynik;
        xi:=xi+h;
    end;
    Result:=Wynik;
 end;

    function TForm1.CalkaNiedomiar (odx,dox:extended; n:integer; f:fx):extended; //trapez z niedomiarem
var i:integer;  xi,h,Wynik:extended;
begin
    Wynik:=0;
    h:=(Dox-Odx)/n;
for i:= 1 to n do
    begin
        Wynik:=f(xi)*h+Wynik;
        xi:=xi+h;
    end;
    Result:=Wynik;
end;

 function TForm1.Calka (odx,dox:extended; n:integer; f:fx):extended;  //trapez
 var i:integer;  xi,h,Wynik:extended;
begin
    Wynik:=0;
    h:=(Dox-Odx)/n;
for i:= 1 to n-1 do
    begin
        Wynik:=f(xi)+Wynik;
        xi:=xi+h;
    end;
    Wynik:=(f(odx) + f(dox) + Wynik)*h/2;
    Result:=Wynik;
end;


end.
```

Comment: What programming language is this ? Pascal ? Delphi ? Modula 2 ? Tags would be good...

Comment: @Pewi: OK - so please edit the question so that people know you're talking about Delphi, and add a `delphi` tag too.

Comment: Reading the enormous amount of code is not enticing. If you want help I suggest you cut the code down to a small section that gives you problems and then tell us what the problem is. At the moment you have given no indication of what fails and what your problem is.

Comment: Could you please try to state clearly what your problem instead of throwing a bunch of code and letting everybody guess?

Comment: currently, its only possible to reply with code quality assesment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will be helpful to you

```
case ( rgMetoda.ItemIndex ) of
  2 : begin CalkaNadmiar;    end;

  3 : begin CalkaNiedomiar; end;   

  else begin               
    //Call other function
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your type definition of the procedural type **TFx** is incompatible with the methods of an object, including a **TForm**.

```
  type
    TFx = function(a: extended): extended;
    TMx = function(a: extended): extended of object;
```

**TFx** is compatible with first class functions, that is functions declared at the unit level, not as members/methods of a class.

**TMx** is compatible with member methods (that is what the "**of object**" means in the declaration.

A **TFx** and a **TMx** are not compatible types because whilst a **TFx** is a pointer to a function, a **TMx** is actually *TWO* pointers: a pointer to an class method *AND* a pointer to a specific instance of that class.

With that information, I think you should be able to see that what you might be after is something like (only significant differences from your code shown, for brevity):

```
  type
    TFx = function(x: extended): extended of object;


  procedure TForm1.ObliczClick(Sender: TObject);
  var
    Wynik, h, xi: real;
    i,n: word;
    fn: TFx;
  begin
    n:=StrToInt(edPrzedzialy.Text);
    h:=(StrToFloat(edDo.Text)-StrToFloat(edOd.Text))/n;
    Wynik:=0;

    if rb1.Checked then fn := f1
    else if rb2.Checked then fn := f2
    else if rb3.Checked then fn := f3;

    for i:=0 to n-1 do
    begin
      xi:=StrToFloat(edOd.Text)+i*h;
      Wynik:= Wynik + fn(xi)*h;
    end;
    pnWynik.Caption:= FloatToStr(Wynik);

    ..
  end;
```

Alternatively, since your **f1**, **f2** and **f3** functions do not actually need to be member methods of **TForm** (they make no use of any instance data) you could leave the **TFx** declaration as it is and simply move the **f1**, **f2** and **f3** outside of the class and simply declare them as first class functions in the unit implementation section:

Note also that in either case, the **TFx** type itself is not needed outside of the implementation section either (based on the code you have posted, tho in the broader context this may not be the case):

implementation

```
  type
    TFx = function(x: extended): extended of object;


  function f1(x: Extended): Extended;
  begin
    result:=sqr(x)+ 2;
  end;


  function f2(X: Extended): Extended;
  begin
    result:=3*x - 8;
  end;


  function f3(X: Extended): Extended;
  begin
    result:=sin(x) + Pi;
  end;



  procedure TForm1.ObliczClick(Sender: TObject);
  var
    Wynik, h, xi: real;
    i,n: word;
    fn: TFx;
  begin
    n:=StrToInt(edPrzedzialy.Text);
    h:=(StrToFloat(edDo.Text)-StrToFloat(edOd.Text))/n;
    Wynik:=0;

    if rb1.Checked then fn := f1
    else if rb2.Checked then fn := f2
    else if rb3.Checked then fn := f3;

    for i:=0 to n-1 do
    begin
      xi:=StrToFloat(edOd.Text)+i*h;
      Wynik:= Wynik + fn(xi)*h;
    end;
    pnWynik.Caption:= FloatToStr(Wynik);

    ..
  end;
```